# Two test cases giving me a nightmare

Tags: c, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

This is a code designed to multiply a matrix by another while skipping any unnecessary multiplication (Ones where either of the multipliers is 0)
I'm required to submit it for a course but I keep getting told 2 cases of the 10 just don't go through, what am I doing wrong here? I mean I know that it looks hideous and it's far from ideal in efficiency but I've reached the point where I just wanna be done with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int anr, anc, bnr, bnc, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &anr);
    scanf("%d", &anc);
    int a[anr][anc];
    for (i=0; i<anr; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<anc; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    scanf("%d", &bnr);
    scanf("%d", &bnc);
    int b[bnr][bnc];
    for (i=0; i<bnr; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<bnc; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    if (anc!=bnr)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int k;
        int out[anr][bnc];
        for (i=0;i<anr;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<bnc;j++)
            {
                out[i][j]=0;
                for (i=0;i<anr;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<bnc;j++)
            {
                out[i][j]=0;
                for (k=0;k<bnr;k++)
                {
                    if ((a[i][k]!=0) && (b[k][j]!=0))
                    {
                        out[i][j]=a[i][k]*b[k][j]+out[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            }
        }
        for (i=0;i<anr;i++)
        {
            
            for (j=0;j<bnc;j++)
            {
                printf("%d ", out[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? You start two loops using the i/j variables within two loops using the same i/j variables?

Comment: Without understanding the above, I'm immediately suspicious of doing `out[i][j]=0;` in two different places.

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste error by a very sleepy student. My advice: get some rest :)

Comment: Welp, it seems the code is working, the test cases asked for "Not Valid" in case the matrices' dimensions weren't appropriate for multiplication. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've made a copy/paste error somewhere along the line between writing the code and posting it here- you loop over i and j within a loop over the same variables! This is obviously an issue. Without knowing what the code you're actually running is, it's not possible to say much about the specifics, but there are a few things that will help you more generally.

**Comment your code.** I cannot stress this enough. It's important in any kind of programming but it becomes much, much more so in numerical algorithms. Don't rely on your memory- you will make mistakes and they will become invisible to you that way. Simply going through the code and commenting each operation would make it very obvious that you were looping over the indices twice and nested, but it's very easy to look at the same code for hours on end and miss mistakes because they become part of the scenery.

Secondly, separate the logic into as small of parts as you can. Rather than loop over the result's entries, initialize the output array to zero, then loop over the index for the inner product, move the initialization into its own loop. It's a very simple task to move it back into a single loop, but separating it until you ensure you have correct code is an easy way to isolate problems and ensure, for example, that you aren't initializing to zero at the wrong level of nesting, or after you've calculated some results.

Finally, check your work at each step. Verify that you're reading in the correct values for a, then do the same for b. Make sure that your output is initialized to zero. If those aren't correct and you're searching in the multiplication code for a problem, you'll never find the issue. Then find the test case or cases that fail- print out the inputs and your output. If the issue is obvious, great. If not, see if you can construct a simpler example that also fails and go from there.

The overarching theme here is simplifying and clarifying the code as much as possible. The less you have to keep track of in your head, the easier it is to find issues. If you later want to condense the code, it'll be easy to figure out where each piece goes and if you introduce a problem you'll know exactly how, because you're starting with correct code.